# Authentik exposes protected path

Tags: node.js, nginx-reverse-proxy

I have a web app running on node.js (specifically Send by Firefox). I want to restrict access to internal users only, so I've set up nginx proxy manager with Authentik for authentication. The download path is currently accessible to anyone with the link, and this is working as intended. However, clicking on the logo of the page redirects to the home page where the upload feature is located, thereby bypassing the intended restrictions. Interestingly, upon reloading the page, Authentik is triggered and authentication works as expected.

I'm almost done with the entire setup, but I'm stuck on this last step which is causing me a lot of trouble. I've tried various approaches, but none seem to work. Any help in resolving this issue would be greatly appreciated. Currently, I have allowed access for the path `^/download/*` in Authentik. I assume it's because of that.